# Contains returning false

Tags: c#, contains

i have code like this

```
foreach (string item in summaryList)
{
    //kelola data
    if(item.Contains("Central"))
    {
        targetSummary = System.Math.Round(_context.Target.Where(x => x.Month == monthId && x.Region.Contains("Central") && x.Type == "SellThru").Select(y => y.Target1 ?? 0).Sum(), 2);
    }
    if (item.Contains("East"))
    {
        targetSummary = System.Math.Round(_context.Target.Where(x => x.Month == monthId && x.Region.Contains("East") && x.Type == "SellThru").Select(y => y.Target1 ?? 0).Sum(), 2);
    }
    if (item.Contains("West"))
    {
        targetSummary = System.Math.Round(_context.Target.Where(x => x.Month == monthId && x.Region.Contains("West") && x.Type == "SellThru").Select(y => y.Target1 ?? 0).Sum(), 2);
    }
    else
    {
        targetSummary = System.Math.Round(_context.Target.Where(x => x.Month == monthId && x.Region.Contains(item) && x.Type == "SellThru").Select(y => y.Target1 ?? 0).Sum(), 2);
    }
}
```

and the summaryList data is

> "ID-TR-Central, ID-TR-Java, ID-TR-East, ID-TR-West"

i dont know why

> item.Contains("Central") and item.Contains("East")

is returning false that makes targetSummary value is infinity, but

> item.Contains("West")

is doing fine

i just dont know what is my mistakes. sorry about my english, i hope you understand and i appreciate your help. 
thanks

Comment: We can't help really help you since we do not know what `item` contains. Just debug your application and see if it really does. Best display everything in `summaryList` to check.

Comment: also, your first two `if` statements will get overridden by the `if-else` statement.

Comment: i have already debug it and `item.Contains("Central") and item.Contains("East")` returning nothing but `item.Contains("West")` is not. so i assume that my `if statement` is wrong?

Comment: @AndhikaKurniaAufaAzham put a breakpoint or a watch on "item" and verify that it contains what you think it contains. This is a pretty common issue. Also, as John pointed out you want `else if` on those two if statements before the else.

Comment: Also, `Contains` returns a `bool`, it won't ever return `null`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto okay, i mean it return false. sorry, i will change the title

Comment: [Contains cannot return null](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L2128-L2130), it returns a value type.... and now you've edited your question, so me looking this up was pointless.

Comment: @john i just edit the title that i type it wrong. sorry

Answer (score 1):

First thing: Post your code for populating summaryList. I assume you meant it's actually `{"ID-TR-Central", "ID-TR-Java", "ID-TR-East, "ID-TR-West"}`, not `"ID-TR-Central, ID-TR-Java, ID-TR-East, ID-TR-West"`.

If you really are feeding a single string, then every criteria is going to be matched and targetSummary will be overwritten.

If not, you still have a problem because your last if statement contains an else branch. You can see more clearly what would happen if your string doesn't contain "West" with reformatting:

```
foreach (string item in summaryList)
{
    //kelola data
    if(item.Contains("Central"))
    {
        targetSummary = System.Math.Round(_context.Target.Where(x => x.Month == monthId && x.Region.Contains("Central") && x.Type == "SellThru").Select(y => y.Target1 ?? 0).Sum(), 2);
    }

    if (item.Contains("East"))
    {
        targetSummary = System.Math.Round(_context.Target.Where(x => x.Month == monthId && x.Region.Contains("East") && x.Type == "SellThru").Select(y => y.Target1 ?? 0).Sum(), 2);
    }

    if (item.Contains("West"))
    {
        targetSummary = System.Math.Round(_context.Target.Where(x => x.Month == monthId && x.Region.Contains("West") && x.Type == "SellThru").Select(y => y.Target1 ?? 0).Sum(), 2);
    }
    else
    {
        targetSummary = System.Math.Round(_context.Target.Where(x => x.Month == monthId && x.Region.Contains(item) && x.Type == "SellThru").Select(y => y.Target1 ?? 0).Sum(), 2);
    }
```

The first two conditions don't matter because your final condition forces anything without "West" into the final else branch. targetSummary will be overwritten regardless of previous matching conditions.

Comment: yes, i know my fault. i have to use else if to my two if statement. thanks